# How to Plot Pre-Averaged Time Series Data in KQL Without Using Summarize?

Tags: azure, plot, time-series, kql, azure-log-analytics

I am currently working on creating a dashboard graph, where my objective is to plot two different series on a timechart. The two series in question are represented by the `processingRate` and `inputRate` columns in my dataset.

Each of these series represents rates that have already been averaged over specified time intervals (e.g., every 5 seconds). As a result, the data is already in a form that I want to visualize, and I don't need to aggregate it further.

My challenge is in plotting these pre-averaged rates without applying additional bin-summarization over a time interval, as this would distort the already averaged data.

How can I achieve this and display both series on the same timechart without further time binning or summarization? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

My pseudo code looks like this:

```
// Join the tables and render the timechart
let AnalysisTbl = InputRateAnalysisTbl
    | join kind=inner ProcessingRateAnalysisTbl on applicationId_s, TimeGenerated
    | project inputRate, processingRate, applicationId_s, TimeGenerated;
AnalysisTbl
| render timechart with x-axis being TimeGenerated and y-axis being inputRate and processingRate
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a solution to my problem. The key lay in harmonizing the structure of the `InputRateAnalysisTbl` and `ProcessingRateAnalysisTbl` tables and then utilizing the `union` operator.

Here's how I went about it:

First, I added a new column rateName to each table to tag the rates:

```
let InputRateAnalysisTbl = SparkMetric_CL
    | where clusterName_s contains "Name"
    | where metric_type_s == "Meter"
    | extend rateName = "inputRate"
    | extend rate = m1_rate_d
    | project rateName,rate, applicationId_s, TimeGenerated, name_s;
```

Secondly, I mirrored these changes on the ProcessingRateAnalysisTbl:

```
let ProcessingRateAnalysisTbl = SparkMetric_CL
    | where clusterName_s contains "Name"
    | where metric_type_s == "Meter"
    | extend rateName = "processRate"
    | extend rate = m1_rate_d
    | project rateName, rate, applicationId_s, TimeGenerated, name_s;
```

Finally, I used union to combine the two tables and then rendered the timechart:

```
union InputRateAnalysisTbl, ProcessingRateAnalysisTbl
| order by TimeGenerated asc
| render timechart
```

Felt a little counter intuitive.